# Is Ember.js Object observer equivalent to ES6 Harmony Object.observe?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ecmascript-harmony, object.observe

Looking at the new observe ES6 featues inside object, I was wondering whether Ember and ES6 are equivalent or different?  Can we use the [Watchjs](https://github.com/melanke/Watch.JS) polyfill safely with ember?

Comment: Nit: Object.observe is _not_ in ES6.

Comment: @Niit do check this out http://addyosmani.com/blog/a-few-new-things-coming-to-javascript/

Comment: The blog might be misleading. Object.observe has recently been given "proposal" status for _ES7_, not ES6.

Answer (score 4):

> Looking at the new observe ES6 featues inside object, I was wondering whether Ember and ES6 are equivalent or different?

Most definitely different. EmberJs has it own system, where every "model" (object whose properties may be observed), is wrapped in an instance of `Ember.Object`.
The `Ember.Object` base class provides all the mechanisms for listening for property changes.
In order to use them, all one needs to do is `.get()` and `.set()` to access and mutate its properties.

> Can we use the Watchjs polyfill safely with ember?

I have not tried this before, but I would caution against it, as my educated guess is that it will **not** work. This is because, as mentioned above, Ember relies on `get`ters and `set`ters to listen for changes on object properties, not `Object.observe`. So even if you use this WatchJs (or any other polyfill), EmberJs app would be oblivious to the changes, because `Ember.Object` does not understand or use this at the moment.